# Plugin not getting updated on deployment

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have somehow got into a strange situation with my CRM system.

A plugin I have developed is not getting updated correctly when the solution is imported. When I choose to maintain the customisations the plugin updates dont get applied, but when I choose to overwrite customisations the steps get doubled up and so the plugin gets fired twice.

Has this happened to anyone else? How do I stop this from happening?

Thanks

Comment: Never press the "overwrite customisations" option! it breaks organisations. You will probably find that you can now only deploy using the overwrite customisations button. This is because you deployed everything to the unmanaged layer... the unmanaged layer takes precedence over the managed layer and so this deployment will therefore overrule future deployments. 
The only fix is to rebuild the organisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a similar situation where I had plugins registered twice after importing.

I believe the way I solved this was:

1. Use the plugin registration tool to remove the plugin from the server you are deploying to.
2. Reimport the solution.

I can't see you doing any major damage here, but I would suggest backing up the server first because I'm not 100% on this one.

Comment: I removed the plugin using the tool and every import after that seems to be going well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you assigning a strong name to the assembly?  I've seen this kind of thing happen in CRM 4.0.  If you don't assign a strong name with a key, CRM doesn't seem to see that it is the same assembly.

Comment: How can i check if a strong name has been assigned?

Comment: @jimminybob - it will have a security key in the project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc31ft41%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy the plugins using the plugin registration tool, solution deployment will duplicate all of the steps as it does not recognise the deployed plugin steps as their ID is changed.

If plugin assembly is deployed without the steps, you've forgotten to add the steps into the "Sdk Message Processing Steps" section of the solution.

@JamesWood approach will always work but is very heavy handed for a production environment, an IIS Reset and restart of the MSCRM services (in services.msc) usually clears any cached plugin assembly, while a redeployment should only be needed/used in dire situations.

Comment: FYI - also deployment usually duplicates plugin steps if you deploy the managed solution to the unmanaged layer, as more often then not the plugin steps do not exist in the unmanaged layer.